# Selector shows ID instead of CD after exception

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to filter the Case classes based on the contract selected. If a wrong Case class is selected for particular contract then I am throwing an exception on Class ID field. 
Below is the line of code I have used to throw an exception

```
    throw new PXSetPropertyException<CRCase.caseClassID>("Incorrect Case Class for Contract");
```

[image]

After the exception, the selector shows ID instead CD value. can anyone tell me why?

Comment: what event are you throwing the exception in?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to have more detail, like the whole function where you added your code.

Depending on where you are throwing that exception, you may be cancelling the event sequence.

The events for trigger in certain order, and the PXSelector attribute uses DAC events to update and subtitute the field value in the UI with the display value.

Try moving your exception to the FieldValidating event method in the graph.